# Convert Iterable<Entity> to list - mongoDB Java

Tags: java, mongodb

what is the most efficient way to convert Iterable to list?
below is my code:

for slower collection:

```
Iterable<TestEntity> entityResult = testCollection.find(and(
                or(
                    geoWithin("aLocation", BasicDBObject.parse(area)),
                    geoWithin("bLocation", BasicDBObject.parse(area))
                ),
                lte(START_DATE, anotherDate),
                gte(END_DATE, Date2),
                and(exists(STATUS), ne(STATUS, "TEST"))
        )).maxTime(mongoDisasterMaxExecutionMaxTime, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

        List<TestEntity> testSummary = StreamSupport.stream(entityResult.spliterator(), true).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

but this takes almost 15 seconds for 80k records. I have another collection, which take about a second for 30k records.

I also have compound indexes on both collections. So, I don't think there is a issue with mongo returning data slowly. when I print logs for mongoDB `find`, its pretty fast, but the `streamsupport` command takes 15 seconds.

Collection 1 (slow)

```
{
    "_id" : “1234”,
    "orderNumber" : “1234”,
    "lastUpdateDate" : ISODate("2021-09-11T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "lastModifiedTime" : NumberLong(1631400026077),
    "product” : “xyzzy”,
    “Feature” : "1",
    "brand" : "Brand abc”,
    “amountUSD" : 100.2,
    “Desc” : “test”,
    “Desc”2 : “test “2,
    “anotherDate" : ISODate("2021-09-19T00:00:00.000Z"),
    “Date2” : ISODate("2021-09-23T00:00:00.000Z"),
    “IdNew” : “3456”,
    “Count” : 1,
    “customerName" : “Dave”,
    “occuranceTime" : ISODate("2021-09-03T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "status" : “confirmed,
    “aLocation" : [ 
        -100.672735, 
        32.849354
    ],
    “bLocation" : [ 
        -69.816366, 
        42.808233
    ]
}
```

Collection 2 ( not slow)

```
{
        "_id" : “1234”,
    "orderNumber" : “1234”,
    "lastUpdateDate" : ISODate("2021-09-11T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "lastModifiedTime" : NumberLong(1631400026077),
    "product” : “xyzzy”,
    “Feature” : "1",
    "brand" : "Brand abc”,
    “amountUSD" : 100.2,
    “Desc” : “test”,
    “Desc”2 : “test “2,
    “anotherDate" : ISODate("2021-09-19T00:00:00.000Z"),
    “Date2” : ISODate("2021-09-23T00:00:00.000Z"),
    “IdNew” : “3456”,
    “Count” : 1,
    “customerName" : “Dave”,
    “occuranceTime" : ISODate("2021-09-03T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "status" : “confirmed,
    “Location”Id : “8888”,
    “aLocation" : [ 
        3.063211, 
        50.633679
    ]
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate on the differences between the two collections you mentioned (other than number of records)?  The shape of documents will play a large role in performance.  If you have large documents or unbounded arrays, serialization will take a lot longer.  Also, are you using frameworks or any custom codecs?  What driver are you using?

Comment: collection 1 (slower response) has 2 `geoWithin` and 2 date indexes
collection 2  has 1 `geoWithin` and 2 date indexes. But my debugging says, the result is pretty fast from mongo but the conversion to list is slow.

Comment: can you please add sample data - from both collections?

Comment: updated my original question with the collection sample

Comment: ...  and would you please provide the query filter predicate?

Comment: I believe the first line - `Iterable<TestEntity> resultEntity = testCollection.find(...);` is deferred execution, meaning you have only captured the cursor definition, but have not started to fetch from the cursor yet.  The second line is where all the magic happens.  Both fetching and serialization.

Comment: added query filter for the slower collection in original question. for the faster one, its same, just 1 geo location less

Comment: the `OR` clause will force the system to execute effectively 2 queries.  You may want to consider a different schema design to avoid using the `OR`.  At least give it a try via a performance test to see if that change is beneficial.

Comment: makes sense. But to my understanding, I get the `entityResult` pretty fast, the issue starts when I am converting it to list

Comment: exactly - see my comment above about 'deferred execution'...

Comment: thats where I am confused with the solution - even if I bring the `entityResult` faster, I will still have the performance issue because my spiterator will take time to convert it to list, right?
in the second line, we are just manipulating our iterable

Comment: Network latency and serialization are some of the slowest operations in a database application.  But all things equal except for the volume I would expect a linear cost, meaning the 80K dataset should be roughly 2.5 times as long as the 30K dataset.  But not all things are equal - you have an OR condition on the slow query.

Comment: makes sense. thank you so much. I will try and get back